# Поиск для сайта

Tags: веб-программирование

Подскажите скрипт для поиска на сайте. Сайт делаю в Microsoft Office Power Point.

Comment: Если сайт делаете на Power Point, берите поиск от Яндекса. Про пхп тут не может быть и речи.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант подключить внешний поиск например от Яндекса. Он это позволяет. Естественно это в том случае, если сайт будет выложен в Интернете, а не рассчитан на локальную сеть.

http://site.yandex.ru/

Comment: Нет, сайт в сети, но хотелось бы не внешний поиск: он не очень хорошо работает.

Comment: Тогда я бы посоветовал делать сайт на связке HTML+PHP+MySQL или взять уже готовый движок, куда поиск уже встроен, наподобие Drupal, Wordpress, Joomla, и т.п.

Answer (score 0):

На Wordpress отличный сайт можно сделать и модуль поиска там есть